# Auto Scroll on panel vb.net

Tags: vb.net, timer, scrollbar

i am trying to get a automatic scroll going (goes all the way down a panel, then scrolls all the way back up).  I get it to go down to the end of the panel, but cannot get it to come back up. It is set to work on a timer. Here is my code:

```
Private Sub tmrSCROLL_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)      Handles tmrSCROLL.Tick

       pnlScrollFeed.AutoScrollPosition = New Point(pnlScrollFeed.AutoScrollPosition.X, Math.Abs(pnlScrollFeed.AutoScrollPosition.Y) + 1)

        Dim totalHeight As Integer = pnlScrollFeed.VerticalScroll.Maximum
        Dim tempHeight As Integer = pnlScrollFeed.VerticalScroll.Value
        Dim tempDiff As Integer = totalHeight - tempHeight

        If tempDiff > 800 Then
            pnlScrollFeed.AutoScrollPosition = New Point(pnlScrollFeed.AutoScrollPosition.X, Math.Abs(pnlScrollFeed.AutoScrollPosition.Y) + 1)
        ElseIf tempDiff <= 800 Then
            pnlScrollFeed.AutoScrollPosition = New Point(pnlScrollFeed.AutoScrollPosition.X, Math.Abs(pnlScrollFeed.AutoScrollPosition.Y) - 1)
            tempHeight += 1
        End If


    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably works better if you have a variable to tell you which direction to go, then just calculate when the scroll thumb hits the bottom or to top:

```
Private scrollUp As Boolean = False

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
  If scrollUp Then
    Dim scrollY As Integer = -Panel1.AutoScrollPosition.Y - 1
    If scrollY < 0 Then
      scrollUp = False
    Else
      Panel1.AutoScrollPosition = New Point(Panel1.AutoScrollPosition.X, scrollY)
    End If
  Else
    Dim scrollY As Integer = -Panel1.AutoScrollPosition.Y + 1
    If scrollY > Panel1.AutoScrollMinSize.Height - Panel1.ClientSize.Height Then
      scrollUp = True
    Else
      Panel1.AutoScrollPosition = New Point(Panel1.AutoScrollPosition.X, scrollY)
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I end up getting more or less the same result.  Once it gets to the bottom of the vertical scroll, it just stops, it does not go back to the top.

Comment: @popojohn My code is working "as is". My panel has a height of 200 pixels and the AutoScrollMinSize is (0, 500).  I do not have any controls inside, etc.

Comment: Would it matter if the panel is docked to the right? Also my panel has a height of 767.

Comment: @popojohn It still works on my machine when I dock it to the right side.  Make sure you copy the code correctly.  It could be easy to miss some of those "-" (minus) signs.

Comment: Still not wokring.  It only works going back up. Once i start the timer, it does not scroll down.  I reviewed your code and made sure to have the "-" signs!! but nothing works

Comment: @popojohn Well, maybe try adding your code to your post.  Smallest amount of code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: So i found the issue, in this line, the integer is not taking the "-" into account, so i keep getting a positive number.  Hence getting (i.e. 726, instead of -726)    



Dim scrollY As Integer= -pnlScrollFeed.AutoScrollPosition.Y + 1

Comment: finally got it to work!  I needed to add a "-" to scrollY for it to take the negetave value.  Thank you very much for your help!!!